# In django rest framework serializer, how can I return the data of foreign key table along with main table?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have post model and identifier model. Both are related as PK of post is the FK of identifier. While returning the data from post table, I need to return the identifier table data as well. How can I do it efficiently?

models.py

```
class SharedIdentifier(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('post.Post',related_name='ref_posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

serializers.py

```
class SharedIdentifierSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SharedIdentifier
        fields = ('id', 'post', 'label', 'value',)
        read_only_fields = ('post')

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(required=False,)
    ref_user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    ref_user_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), write_only=True, source='ref_user')

    identifier = serializers.CharField(max_length=32, write_only=True)
    identifier_info = SharedIdentifierSerializer(required=False,many=True,read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'author', 'ref_user', 'ref_user_id', 'status', 'message', 'type', 'parent_id', 'rating', 'create_date', 'close_date','identifier','identifier_info',)
        read_only_fields = ('status', 'close_date', 'author', 'ref_user','identifier_info',
```

Comment: can you post your model code? I am not sure I understand the relationship between your models

Comment: Try to add 'source=ref_posts' to your identifier_info serializer field. Looks like it might not know where to look for the data you want.

Comment: @MadWombat It worked. Thanks a ton!!:) Did same thing for ref_user_id in PostSerializer but missed here.

Answer (score 1):

With a [nested relationship](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) on the `Post` model's serializer, that points to the `Identifier` model's serializer.

Comment: Updated question with the code. I have tried this way and it didn't returned identifier_info.